# Negation of a folder in S3 Event Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with an event notification set up. The trigger of the event is `All object create events` and it basically runs a lambda function.

Inside the bucket, I have a bunch of folders, one for each operator in our system.

[image: operator folders]

Inside each operator's folder, there might be a folder called `/exports/`.

**Objective**

For objects created within the `/exports/` folder (under the operator folder), I **do not** want to trigger the event.

Is that possible with S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not supported afaik. You have three options:

1. Use two buckets, one for the dropped items and one for the exports, where each bucket would have a BLAC/ prefix, a CUCC/ prefix etc.
2. Restructure your prefixes within this one bucket to have: import/BLACC/   , import/CUCC/, export/BLACC/, export/CUCC/ and configure the upload trigger on the prefix import/
3. Modify your Lambda function to treat objects with exports/ in their key as a no-op.